# How can I use multiple dynamic DB with single code/project on run time with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to connect dynamic mongo DB with my single code according to sub domain url.

eg.

1. if www.xyz.example.com then mongo DB is xyz
2. if www.abc.example.com then mongo DB is abc
3. if www.efg.example.com then mongo DB is efg

if someone hit www.xyz.example.com url then xyz DB automatically connect. if someone hit www.abc.example.com url then abc DB automatically connect.

but xyz DB connection should not disconnect. it should be remain . Because there is single code/project.

Please give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your application use case so cannot assure the best solution.

One feasible solution is to run 3 `node.js` threads on 3 different `ports`, each connect to a specific DB instance. You can do it by running 3 different `node.js` process with different environment variables. Then forward the requests to each domain to different ports.

This approach has some advantages:

- Ease of configuration, just need to care about deployment setting without `if/else` hacking in source code.
- System availability, if 1 of the 3 DBs is down, only 1 domain affected, the others still work well.

NOTE: This approach just works well with small number of sub domains. If you have 30 sub domains or dynamic domains, then please re-consider your deployment architecture :). You may need to use some more advanced techniques to deal with it. A quick (but not best) way is to maintain a list of `mongoose` instances inside the application during application runtime, each instance is responsible for 1 sub domains. Then use `req.get('host')` to check the sub domain and use the corresponding `mongoose` instance to process the DB operations.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, yes we will have more then 50 sub domains and even dynamic domains too. so can you please suggest some advance technique or any other suitable solution which could be helpful for us.

Comment: It's more about deployment architecture (your complex use case may need container deployment approach) rather than application code. I updated my answer with quick solution. Hope that it can help.